# How to place text after the relative positioned element?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have absolute positioned div tag (child) placed inside relative positioned div tag (parent). I want to show the text after parent div, but it is placed in incorrect position.

*HTML*

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child" style="width: 200px; height: 100px; background-color: red;"></div>
</div>
<p>The text which should be shown after parent div</p>
```

*CSS*

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 30px;
}
```

What to do?

**Updated**

Type mistakes has been corrected.

Solution, proposed by Vitorino Fernandes, to indicate height of the parent div is good. But what to do if I don't know exact height of the parent div? Can I omit the height of the parent div and put the text excatly after it?

Comment: you have another typo `postion`

Answer (score 1):

typo mistake should be `position` not `postion` should be `height:100px` not `height 100px` and add `height` to relative element

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  height:300px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left:30px;
  width: 200px;
  height:100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<p>The text which should be shown after parent div</p>
```

Comment: also typo `left 30px;`

Comment: Typo mistakes is not the main mistakes. The main problem is that the height of the parent element should be indicated.

Comment: Can this problem be solved without indicating the height of the parent div?